# Data not inserting into database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a modal window with a form and it is supposed to submit the field data to the database, not close the modal widow, and then display "You have been RSVP'd" before fading out the modal window.

2 things:

1) On submit, the modal window closes?! It should remain open
2) The data isn't inserting into the database..

**Modal window HTML**

```
<form id="rsvp-yes" action="#" method="post" name="rsvp-yes">
<label for="email">Your E-mail</label>
    <input id="email" class="txt" type="email" name="email" />
    <label for="location">Choose your location</label>
    <select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="None Selected" selected>Select</option>
    <option value="Perth">Perth</option>
    <option value="Brisbane">Brisbane</option>
    <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>
    <option value="Melbourne">Melbourne</option>
    </select>

    <button id="rsvp">RSVP</button></form></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".modalbox").fancybox();
        $("#rsvp").submit(function() { return false; });

        function validateEmail(email) { 
        var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return reg.test(email);
    }

        $("#rsvp").on("click", function(){
            var emailval  = $("#email").val();
            var city      = $("#city").val();
            var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

            if(mailvalid == false) {
                $("#email").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(mailvalid == true){
                $("#email").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(mailvalid == true) {
                //&& msglen >= 4
                // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
                // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
                $("#rsvp").replaceWith("<em>RSVP'ing you...</em>");

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'rsvp-yes.php',
                    data: $("#rsvp-yes").serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data == "true") {
                            $("#rsvp-yes").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                                $(this).before("<p><strong>You have been RSVP'd</strong></p>");
                                setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$city = $_POST['city'];

mysql_connect(myhost,myuser,mypass) or die("Could not connect: " . 
mysql_error());
mysql_query("USE mydbname");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO rsvp-yes (ID, email, city)
VALUES ('NULL', '".$email"', '".$city"')");

?>
```

Comment: First check connection is established or not ?

Comment: This needs basic debugging first. Is the submit button replaced? Is the ajax request fired? What does the ajax request return?

Comment: How can I debug these? And check that connection is established?

Comment: add or `die(mysql_error())` along with your query statement and check what your getting. also trace your ajax request with `firebug` or any other tool

Answer (score 0):

I think your **ID** is autoincreament in database. So instead of

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rsvp-yes (ID, email, city) VALUES ('NULL', '".$email"', '".$city"')");
```

use

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rsvp-yes (ID, email, city) VALUES ('', '".$email"', '".$city"')");
```

remove NULL

Answer (score -1):

You should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` function to prevent from SQL injection. It also prevent error on inserting data because of quote or double quote.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($email);

$city = $_POST['city'];
$city=mysql_real_escape_string($city);
```

Hope your `ID` column is a **primary key** and also an **auto incremented** field. So you should not include `ID` on your sql statement.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rsvp-yes (email, city)
VALUES ('$email', '$city')");
```

Comment: Well, you could equally say, you should use prepared statements (parametrized queries), however this all is not an answer to the question. And please do not propagate deprecated functions like `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: This is not mysql_real_escape_string()problem

Comment: Whoops. Should've escaped them.

Comment: Thanks nirav. Any clues anyone?